# (jQuery) How Still Hover, still showing ... this

Tags: jquery, hover, fade

http://jsfiddle.net/5MwVg/15/

When I still hover , will still showing...

How to ? Thanks so much agian

PS: and so thanks if you and add fade in&out effect....

Comment: What do you want? Your question is unclear. Write in normal english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".post-box").bind('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).find(".readthis").fadeIn()
    })
    $(".post-box").bind('mouseleave', function() {
        elem = $(this)
        setTimeout(function() {
            elem.find(".readthis").fadeOut()
        }, 2000)
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="post-wrapper"> 
    <div class="post-box"> 
        <a style="margin: -5px 0 0 -6px; display: none; position: absolute;" href="#">
        <img src="http://www.filmsys.com/images/star-icon.gif"></a> 
        <img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo1w.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Modified it for you, does that do what you want? In future try be more descriptive in the title, you'll get better answers.